# No puedo centrar form en HTML

Tags: html, css

Quiero centrar un form horizontal y verticalmente (osea que quede al centro de la página en el eje x y en el eje y), pero por alguna razón no puedo centrarlo.

Si me podrían ayudar. El contenedor DIV del form es `display: flex`.

Acá el código HTML y CSS:

```css
body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          font-family: 'Inter', arial;
          background-image: url("files/code-img.jpg");
          
      }
      
      .divform {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
      }
      
      .form {
          background: #ebebeb;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 30px;
          width: 350px;
      }
      
      .form input {
          font-size: 180%;
          border: 1px solid #c9c9c9; 
          border-radius: 5px;
          outline: none;
          width: 300px;
          font-family: 'Inter', arial;
      }
      
      .form button[type=submit] {
          font-size: 140%;
          padding: 5px;
          padding-left: 84px;
          padding-right: 84px;
          background: #0092d2;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 5px;
          color: white;
          margin-top: 5px;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: 'Inter', arial;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Iniciar sesión | Portal Audiovisual</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap?ppp" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="divform">
        <form class="form" method="post" align="center">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ci" placeholder="C.I." required><br>
            <input style="margin-top: 5px" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required><br>
            <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Les dejo una imagen de como se ve:
[image: imagen de como se ve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te faltaría definir una altura para el contenedor de tu `<form>` ocupe el 100% de alto de la pantalla. De esa manera **flex** podrá actuar para centrarlo en el eje **Y**

Para hacerlo puedes usar la unidad relativa **vh** con el valor **100** para indicar que quieres que ocupe el 100% del alto del layout disponible.

```css
body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          font-family: 'Inter', arial;
          background-image: url("files/code-img.jpg");
          
      }
      
      .divform {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          height: 100vh;
      }
      
      .form {
          background: #ebebeb;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 30px;
          width: 350px;
      }
      
      .form input {
          font-size: 180%;
          border: 1px solid #c9c9c9; 
          border-radius: 5px;
          outline: none;
          width: 300px;
          font-family: 'Inter', arial;
      }
      
      .form button[type=submit] {
          font-size: 140%;
          padding: 5px;
          padding-left: 84px;
          padding-right: 84px;
          background: #0092d2;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 5px;
          color: white;
          margin-top: 5px;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: 'Inter', arial;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Iniciar sesión | Portal Audiovisual</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap?ppp" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="divform">
        <form class="form" method="post" align="center">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ci" placeholder="C.I." required><br>
            <input style="margin-top: 5px" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required><br>
            <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me funcionó :)